# redistributing value according to proportion

Tags: algebra-precalculus, statistics

If 1/2 of a population receive £400 each, and the other 1/2 £400 too, then if we redistribute the value from the second population to the first the first will get £800 each.

However I would like to know the general principle for formulating this type of problem. For example I cannot figure out how to restribute from second to first if

- 1st population: 2/3 get £400
- 2nd population: 1/3 get £400

How might I do this?

Comment: 1st pop proportion: $p_1$, first pop receives $m_1$.  2nd pop proportion: $p_2$, second pop receives $m_2$.  You'll have after redistributing the wealth of the second population to the first the first population has now $m_1+m_2\cdot\frac{p_2}{p_1}$

Answer (score 0):

After the redistribution, the first population get

$$400+\frac{3\times 400}{2\times 3}=400+200=600$$

each person.

---

alternative reasoning

---

Assume you have a total population of $9$

Before the redistribution you have

- $6$ persons with $400$ each that is $6\times 400=2,400$ total income Pop #1
- $3$ persons with $400$ each that is $3\times 400=1,200$ total income Pop #2

The total income is now $3,600$ to be divided by 6 persons....

that means $600$ each

Of course you can choose a total number you want as a population. If you choose $n=1$ you get the first formula I showed